# Name for Directed Edges in Digraphs

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, ho.history-overview, terminology, directed-graphs

Graph theory originated in German speaking countries and there directed edges are called "Pfeil" which translates to "arrow", which makes sense, because arrows have distinguishable front end and rear end that resemble the source vertex and target vertex of directed edges.

Now I noticed that in English papers the term "arrow" seems to be less frequent than the term "arc". That seems a little strange because arcs have no clearly distinguishable ends (what would e.g. be the front end of the [Gateway Arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_Arch) of St. Louis, Missouri and what would be its rear end?)

> **Questions:**
>
> - what are the earliest English publications on digraphs and what term is used there "arrow" or "arc"?
> - If there was a change in terminology, when did it happen and what were the influential publications?

Comment: “Arch” and “arc” are distinct English words. Arc is often used to describe a curved trajectory of an object, like a thrown ball, or a shot arrow. From this perspective I think the name makes sense, since a trajectory does have a temporal directionality.

Comment: @IzaakMeckler according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arc) an arc is "something curved or arched"; the temporal interpretation is just one from several possible.

Comment: According to omniscient Wikipedia's page about [Directed Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph), "directed arc" is a possible alternative to "arrow"; but apparently the "directed" attribute is dropped in most publications that use the term "arc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not the first, but the 1956 paper of Ford and Fulkerson, ["Maximal Flow through a Network"](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/lans/readings/routing/ford-max_flow-1956.pdf) used "arcs".